# fetch json data to state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I fetch and get the data, I want to save it to state using setState as an array or object so I can call to each field in the return part and display it on screen

but I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object
> with keys {gender, name, location, email, login, dob, registered,
> phone, cell, id, picture, nat}). If you meant to render a collection
> of children, use an array instead

```
import {useState} from 'react'

export default function Test(){
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const getInfo = async () =>{
        const response = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api');
        if(response.status === 200){
            const res = await response.json();
            setData(res.results[0]);
            // also try this: setData(res) 
            // also try this: setData(res.result)
        }else{
            throw new Error('Unable to fetch data')
        }
    }
    
    return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={() =>{getInfo()}}>fetch data</button>
            {data}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: what is the result of console.log(res.results[0])?

Comment: `{getInfo()}` is interpreted as an object. Remove the curly braces and try `<button onClick={getInfo}>fetch data</button>` instead.

Comment: @BlackMath ```const getInfo = async () =>{``` i don't think so - this declares a function

Comment: why not? it is a function of course @Antax

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this codesandbox URL, I feel you can make use of useEffect for your usecase [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-dijkstra-py7ld?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your are getting an response which is not an array. You are trying to use higher order array methode on a object. Use ,

```
const resultArray = res.results;
```

get the array of results from the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `res.results[0]` is the object that has the keys of `gender`, `name`, `location`, `email`, `login`, `dob`, `registered`, `phone`, `cell`, `id`, `picture`, `nat`. But you are trying to set the state value `data` as an array.

You should set the data type to object.

In render function to browse the data, iterate the keys using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

---

for the onClick triggering way in render, you don't need to `() => {getInfo()}` since there is no specific parameters passed to the method, just use `onClick={getInfo}`.

```
import {useState} from 'react'

export default function Test(){
    const [data, setData] = useState({});

    const getInfo = async () =>{
        const response = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api');
        if(response.status === 200){
            const res = await response.json();
            setData(res.results[0]);
            // also try this: setData(res) 
            // also try this: setData(res.result)
        }else{
            throw new Error('Unable to fetch data')
        }
    }
    
    return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={getInfo}>fetch data</button>
            {Object.keys.map(key => (<div>
               {key} : {data.key}
            </div>)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The data being returned here from "https://randomuser.me/api" is not a simple JSON data. It is really a JSON object with multiple sub-objects in it such as "name", which is again having "title", "first" and "last" as sub-objects. This is the reason you are getting error that "found: object with keys".

If you are looking for dummy data for testing purpose, I would suggest you to check "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/", which is a good source of dummy JSON data.

I have updated your code as under, which is returning data in proper JSON format and can be assigned to state.

```
  const getInfo = async () =>{
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    
    if(response.status === 200){
        const res = await response.json();
        console.log(res)
        setData(res);        
    }else{
        throw new Error('Unable to fetch data')
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem might be that you are using `setData(res.results[0]);`

I bet that this is an Object and not an Array.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

states that the setData function only stores arrays.

try using

```
const [data, setData] = useState({});
```

and see if that is working

if it is not working give us the ouput of `console.log(res.results)`
and `console.log(typeof(res.results[0]))`